# variable number of parameters in function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, managed-c++

I've a pointer to the function that can point to the function with one, two or more args.

```
double (*calculate)(int);

double plus(int a, int b){ return a+b; }

double sin(int a){ return Math::Sin(a); }
```

how is it possible for me to use

```
calculate = plus; 
calculate = sin;
```

in the same program. Not allowed to change functions plus and sin. Writing in managed c++;

I've tried `double (*calculate)(...);` but that's not working.

Comment: This was already asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11037393/2036917

Comment: it transfers num of args, it's not possible in my algo. I wanna make a kind of function overloading.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of `plus` to `calculate` is a type violation, and when calling `calculate` later leads to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so anything (bad) can happen.

You might be interested in [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) (but I have no idea if it works with managed C++).

Answer (score 0):

You can try use something like this:

```
struct data
{
  typedef double (*one_type) ( int a );
  typedef double (*other_type) ( int a, int b );

  data& operator = ( const one_type& one ) 
  {
    d.one = one;
    t = ONE_PAR;
    return *this;
  }

  data& operator = ( const other_type& two ) 
  {
    d.two = two;
    t = TWO_PAR;
    return *this;
  }

  double operator() ( int a )
  {
    assert( t == ONE_PAR );
    return d.one( a );
  }

  double operator() ( int a, int b )
  {
    assert( t == TWO_PAR );
    return d.two( a, b );
  }

  union func
  {
    one_type one;
    other_type two;
  } d;


  enum type
  {
    ONE_PAR,
    TWO_PAR
  } t;
};
double va( int a ) 
{
  cout << "one\n";
}
double vb( int a, int b ) 
{
  cout << "two\n";
}
```

This works fine:

```
data d;
d = va;
d( 1 );
d = vb;
d( 1, 2 );
```

Comment: unfortunately, isnt working in managed c++