# C++ call arbitrary function for each element

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a list of String and for each of those I want to call an arbitrary function with different required parameters.

Example:

```
void method1(QString name, int foo1){}
void method2(QString name, int foo2, bool flag(){}

QStringList list;
list << "ELEM1" << "ELEM2";
```

And now I want a function to which I can pass any function and its called with given values for each element in list

```
void callForAll((MyClass::*pt2ConstMember)(QString,X,X)){
    foreach(QString element, list){
        (*m_class.*pt2ConstMember)(element,X,X);
    }
}

callForAll(&MyClass::method1, 4);
callForAll(&MyClass::method2, 6, false)
```

At its core it seems like I want to do something like this:
[C++: Function pointer to functions with variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037393/c-function-pointer-to-functions-with-variable-number-of-arguments) or am I going the wrong way with this`?

To make things even more complicated the callForAll function should not be called directly but using signal/slots in Qt. So I would need signal with variadic parameters and the function pointer:

In sender class:
Signal:

```
template<typename F, typename ...PP >
void sigForAll(F f, PP&& ... pp);
```

Usage:

```
emit sigForAll(&Receiver::method1, 5, true)
```

In receiver class:

```
 template<typename F, typename ...PP >
 void ForAll(F f, PP&& ... pp);
```

In third class containing member instances of sender and receiver class:

```
 connect(m_sender, SIGNAL(sigForAll(F f, PP&& ... pp)), m_receiver, SLOT(ForAll(F f, PP&& ... pp)))
```

Comment: This can be done with variadic templates and ````std::any```` as container and using a templated ````std::any_cast````. Or with ````std::function```` and ````std::bind````. Or with lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda. It will get optimized much better than a pointer-to-member solution:

```
template <typename F>
void callForAll(F const& f) {
    foreach(QString element, list) {
        f(element);
    }
}

callForAll([&m_class](QString const& s){ m_class.method1(s, 4); });
callForAll([&m_class](QString const& s){ m_class.method2(s, 6, false); });
```

Comment: Is the lambda approach viable for using in QT slots, when the class with the signal has no access to the member of m_class?

Comment: Probably. You need to provide more details in the question for that.

Comment: nvm I noticed that I could put the arbitrary callFunction simply into the sender ...